# dojo rel 1.6 on firefox portable app

Tags: firefox, dojo, portability

is it Dojo 1.6 fully supported on Firefox Portable App 24 ? we are experiencing random browser crashes that instead we don't have when the same app is running in Firefox browser (same version)

many thanks for any support

Answer (score 0):

Dojo 1.6 release docs here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/releasenotes/1.6.html

Dojo 1.6.1 supports Firefox 4 - 10, but 1.6 makes no mention of this.

No mention is made of Firefox Portable.  Given the discrepancy between the portable/nonportable versions, I would suspect this might be a Firefox Portable issue.